# Configure Android EditText to allow decimals and number,not allow begin with '.' or '00' and '000' and so on

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers, decimal

I have an Android EditText that I want to have the number keyboard come up.

If I set the `android:inputType` to `numberdecimal|number`, I get the number keyboard and the ability to type in decimal and number. but It can input `'.00222''0000'`else,It is not my want,And if I compile project at `android 4.4.2` and it works that my expected,but use `Android 6.0`,It's not my expected.
How do you get the number keyboard with the ability to type in decimals and number in `Android 6.0`?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way other than validating the input ... `android:inputType` is only a hint ... and since you can have custom keyboards on android there is no common way for doing this ... try to validate the input on every text change by yourself

Comment: "If I set the android:inputType to numberdecimal|number, I get the number keyboard and the ability to type in decimal and number" -- not necessarily. There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with hundreds of soft keyboards, and users can install others from the Play Store. As Selvin notes, `android:inputType` is a hint, not a demand. What each keyboard does with respect to your desired `inputType` **is up to the developers of the keyboard, not you**.

Comment: You can set textWatcher on edittext and check input in afterTextChanged function. if user type any char which is not suitable for your demand then remove last character and move cursor one char back.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late to post my suggestion, however, I think it might help others.

With the input type set to "NumberDecimal" like android:inputType="numberDecimal" (i.e., to achieve a keyborad with only number and decimal point available), you can set up an input filter to prevent users from entering any number you don't want like ".XX", "00" etc. Please find below for the example.

```
    public class NumberDecimalInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    private int numbOfDigitsAfterDecimalPoint_;
    private boolean firstDigitIsZero_;

    public NumberDecimalInputFilter(int numbOfDigitsAfterDecimalPoint) {
        numbOfDigitsAfterDecimalPoint_ = numbOfDigitsAfterDecimalPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        int dotPosition = -1;
        int desLength = dest.length();

        if (desLength == 0) {
            if (source.equals(".")) { //do not allow nothing preceding the dot
                return "";
            }
            firstDigitIsZero_ = source.equals("0") ? true : false;
        }

        if (firstDigitIsZero_ && desLength == 1 && !source.equals(".")) { //only allow a dot follows the first 0, i.e., to prevent 00, 01 or 001 ...
            return "";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < desLength; i++) {
            char c = dest.charAt(i);
            if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
                dotPosition = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dotPosition >= 0) {
            // protects against many dots
            if (source.equals(".") || source.equals(",")) {
                return "";
            }
            // if the text is entered before the dot
            if (dend <= dotPosition) {
                return null;
            }
            if (desLength - dotPosition > numbOfDigitsAfterDecimalPoint_) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage - set the edit text to allow only two digits after the decimal point.

```
EditTextInstance.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new NumberDecimalInputFilter(2)});
```